# how to print response without ngFor

Tags: angular

this is my function it's working fine

```
function(id){
    this.myservice
      .getUserById(id).subscribe(
        result => {
          this.myDatabyId = result.json();
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error.json());
        }
      );
  }
```

response is like this

```
[
  {
    "role": "admin",
    "_id": "5c2dc074d6bfba36b41b34de",
    "name": "admin",
    "email": "admin@gmail.com",
    "username": "admin",
  }
]
```

How do i print this in my template

```
{{myDatabyId | json}}
```

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <form name="form" novalidate *ngFor="let item of myDatabyId">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"  [(ngModel)]="item.name" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email"  [(ngModel)]="item.email" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username"  [(ngModel)]="item.username" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="role">Role</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="role"  [(ngModel)]="item.role" required />
        </div>
    </form>
```

I used *ngFor it's wrong because it's only one always not more then one

also i try to get ngModel value

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="confirm()">OK</button>

confirm(){
    console.log("Confirm",name);
  }
```

it return undefiend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one item, then you can maintain a single object instead of an array.

code :

```
myDatabyId;

function(id){
    this.myservice
      .getUserById(id).subscribe(
        result => {
          this.myDatabyId = result.json()[0];  // get first item from an array
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error.json());
        }
      );
  }
```

And in your html - you can do `[(ngModel)]="myDatabyId.name"`

```
<div class="modal-body" *ngIf="myDatabyId">
   <form name="form" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"  [(ngModel)]="myDatabyId.name" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email"  [(ngModel)]="myDatabyId.email" required />
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username"  [(ngModel)]="myDatabyId.username" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="role">Role</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="role"  [(ngModel)]="myDatabyId.role" required />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: I got error Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 18 in [myDatabyId?.name=$event] in ng:///AppModule/UseradminComponent.html@44:74 ("l for="name">Name</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"  [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="myDatabyId?.name" required />

Comment: Yes, you cannot use `scope resolution (?.)` against `ngModel`, because that acts as a setter and getter variable. I have updated answer without using that. Please check

Comment: You can also check the working demo here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gy5tqr

Comment: How to get this value in my component confirm(){
    console.log("Confirm",name);
  }

Comment: Just print `console.log(this.myDatabyId.name);` inside `confirm()` You should get that value. Check update demo as well.